# How can I make a custom Pin It button to create the Pinterest overlay?

Tags: javascript, sharing, pinterest

*Note: this is not a duplicate question.*

Buzzfeed has this interesting custom Pinterest button at the top of their posts-- [here is a sample post](http://www.buzzfeed.com/lorynbrantz/disney-princesses-as-office-supplies#.imA4mvWD0r), and here is the button you want to click:

[image]

So how do they do this? None of the official Pinterest developer documentation explains how to do this. And I can't find anything else here on Stack Overflow that explains how to accomplish this particular UX.

Comment: That’s likely something they simply built themselves – so you won’t find it in the Pinterest documentation, because it is not “from” Pinterest. Looks like a simple overlay that shows a couple of images, and buttons on top of them that trigger the “normal” share functionality that _is_ documented.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up finding a very simple, elegant solution here: https://halgatewood.com/how-to-customize-the-pin-it-button-for-pinterest

```
<script>
function pinIt()
{
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');
  e.setAttribute('src','https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);
  document.body.appendChild(e);
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:pinIt();">Pin</a>
```

(And obviously, you can change the word "Pin" to an `<img>` or whatever you want in there.)